# Getting 0 in Group By Month

Tags: mysql

My Table structure is like this:

id | bileti_id | status | user_id | point | date

I want to get Number of bileti_id where status is 1 Grouped By Months, but if there is 0 in some month, give me 0 in that month and not just months where are values... So my query returns only months where user made more than 0 bileti_id.

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(`bileti_id`),0) FROM `wp_biletistatus` WHERE `user_id`= 16590 and `status`=1 GROUP BY MONTH(`date`) ORDER BY `date` ASC Limit 10
```

But i have already Query which Calls these months: so i need to connect this query with previous one, to get exactly how much bileti_id user had in these months, with 0 results as well...

Here is second query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(`date`) FROM `wp_biletistatus` WHERE `user_id`= 16590 GROUP BY MONTH(`date`) ORDER BY `date` ASC Limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be closer to what you need, but I am still not sure of the importance or significance of the LIMIT 10. Are you trying to only get data for the users last 10 months? ("ORDER BY `date`" doesn't seem quite right if that is the case.)

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(`date`) AS mName, MONTH(`date`) AS mOrder
, SUM(IF(status=1, 1, 0)) AS c
FROM `wp_biletistatus` 
WHERE `user_id`= 16590
GROUP BY mOrder
ORDER BY mOrder
;
```

Comment: no... the months can change, so table is not a good idea, as my query of months is getting last months.

Comment: Thank you for such help! We are almost there... But i will try to explain again better to make you understand where is now problem. I`m getting this for my Chart graphic. So, on chart with my months query i get data from November to  May (current)...  in your case I`m getting data for all 12 months...  And my query returns: November
December
January
February
March
April
May

Comment: @GuramiTateshvili, Ah, but past one year, either query will end up getting the data for all months regardless of year. Perhaps the WHERE should also have "AND `date` >= now() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH".
...or some more complicated date comparison to force "1st of month"

Comment: Me and you did it :)       SELECT MONTHNAME(`date`) AS mName, MONTH(`date`) AS mOrder
, SUM(IF(status=1, 1, 0)) AS c
FROM `wp_biletistatus` 
WHERE `user_id`= 16590 AND date >= now() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH
GROUP BY mOrder
ORDER BY `date` ASC